# What's the English words for "pan domain name"?

Tags: dns

the main domain is www.abc.com
I use the DNS to set all sub-domains *.abc.com point to the www.abc.com.

How to say this in english?

I find the wikis, is it correct for 'pan-domain name resolving'

> Wildcard DNS records Main article:
>   Wildcard DNS record The domain name
>   system supports wildcard domain names
>   which are names that start with the
>   asterisk label, '*', e.g.,
>   *.example.[3][17] DNS records belonging to wildcard domain names
>   specify rules for generating resource
>   records within a single DNS zone by
>   substituting whole labels with
>   matching components of the query name,
>   including any specified descendants.
>   For example, in the DNS zone
>   x.example, the following configuration
>   specifies that all subdomains
>   (including subdomains of subdomains)
>   of x.example use the mail exchanger
>   a.x.example. The records for
>   a.x.example are needed to specify the
>   mail exchanger. As this has the result
>   of excluding this domain name and its
>   subdomains from the wildcard matches,
>   all subdomains of a.x.example must be
>   defined in a separate wildcard
>   statement. The role of wildcard
>   records was refined in RFC 4592,
>   because the original definition in RFC
>   1034 was incomplete and resulted in
>   misinterpretations by
>   implementers.[17]

**Wildcard DNS record**
I think this the computer-specific term which I searched for.

I want to build a wildcard dns resolving in my local-network for windows environment...
I'm search for a tutorial....
**Any suggestions?**

Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Ask at http://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: **A redirect?** I don't know what "pan" means.

Comment: pan means: *.abc.com  it means resolving all sub-domain to the main domain.

Comment: This might be less specific, but it is to the same point: "URL canonization".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for wildcard DNS records.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record

Comment: I'm a chinese, I couldn't find the correct translation from chinese to english. 

I have a chinese term stand for "wildcard domain name resolving"

Did it have a english term for that?

Comment: I don't think there's a single word for it, it's just a DNS wildcard.

Comment: @bentz, hi, I am a Chinese, you can say the Chinese characters if you'd like to. XD

Comment: @Dante ,"泛域名"用英文怎么说？找了个计算机机中英对照的网站，还是台湾的，还不能访问。。。

谢谢先兄弟~

Comment: @Dante www.cybertranslator.idv.tw/glossary/computer.htm这是我找的。翻过去看了，没有“泛域名”对应的英文。

如果以"DNS wildcard resolving" 来翻译它合适不?

Comment: @bentz, http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18470/what-is-the-exact-term-for-resolving-all-sub-domains-stackexchange-com-to-www

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what you mean. You could set CNAME records on them and point it to www.abc.com, but I don't know if that's what you mean.

Comment: resolving all sub-domain *.abc.com to www.abc.com.  How to say this in english? did it have a computer-term for it?